# getRowData in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, selector

`getRowData` function in **jqgird**,I notice that there is a selector look like `"$("td", ind)"`,
I haven't seen this before, and more weird, It got different results when worked in chrome and firefox.

I known first parameter means select all `"td"`s,but what's the use of second parameter?

Comment: ind it is parameter that declared above

Comment: `ind` is context and in the code of `getRowData` it is a DOM element of some from `<tr>` elements. So `$("td", ind)` select all cells (`<tr>` elements) of the row (of the `<tr>`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument is the context, from the docs -

> By default, selectors perform their searches within the DOM starting
>   at the document root. However, an alternate context can be given for
>   the search by using the optional second parameter to the $() function.
>
> Internally, selector context is implemented with the .find() method,
>   so $('span', this) is equivalent to $(this).find('span').

From - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

So in your example the code will be searching for `td`s inside the `ind` object.

Comment: @user1021531 - it's a pleasure! I'd really appreciate it if you could accept it if it did help. Thanks :)